# Edittext remove focus

Tags: android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a dialog in which there is an `edittext` and `datepicker`. After I set the date using a `DatePicker`, the date focus goes to `edittext` and shows the keyboard.How can I disable showing the keyboard after setting date.

Answer (score 0):

you can use beneath line to set the edit text to non editable

```
android:focusable="false" // disable the editable in edit text
android:inputType="date"  // input type
```

Then, you can set onclick listener to the edit text. Once it click then you can call the datepiker and after clicking ok button in datepicker set the date into the edit text and it can not be editable.